# CorelDraw VBA macro error: "Object Required"

Tags: vba, draw, coreldraw

I am creating a macro for CorelDraw which will import a file from a given folder when a button called `Generate` is pressed. When trying to assign a filepath to a variable, I get the following error:

> Object Required

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Design Of Item'

    Me.DesignList.AddItem ("BIFT")
    Me.DesignList.AddItem ("BIFC1")
    Me.DesignList.AddItem ("BIFC2")
    Me.DesignList.AddItem ("BIFI")

    'Type Of Item'

    Me.TypeList.AddItem ("BIF HOODIE")
    Me.TypeList.AddItem ("BIF T-SHIRT")
    Me.TypeList.AddItem ("BIF SWEAT")
    Me.TypeList.AddItem ("BIF TANK")

    'Colours of the items'

    Me.ColourList.AddItem ("Grey")
    Me.ColourList.AddItem ("White")
    Me.ColourList.AddItem ("Black")
    Me.ColourList.AddItem ("Navy")

    Dim Design As String
    Dim Ctype As String
    Dim Colour As String
    Dim ShirtFPath As String

End Sub

Private Sub GenerateBtn_Click()
    Set ShirtFPath = ("C:\Users\Matt\Pictures\Clothing Line\Shirts")
    MsgBox (ShirtFPath)
    Set Design = DesignList.Value
    Set Ctype = TypeList.Value
    Set Colour = ColourList.Value
End Sub

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click()

    Dim fPath As Object
    Dim sr As ShapeRange

    Set fPath = Me.TB.Value
    If fPath Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use `Set` for object assignment. For intrinsic types (numbers, strings, booleans), omit the word `Set`:

```
ShirtFPath = "C:\Users\Matt\Pictures\Clothing Line\Shirts"
Design = DesignList.Value
Ctype = TypeList.Value
Colour = ColourList.Value
```

Comment: Thank you bond! Been here for like 30 mins not knowing why hahaha.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it can be hard to tell if a property/function (like `Value`) is returning an intrinsic type or an object. The documentation should help clarify that for you.